# How to display in dialog variable from API request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access the variable totalPresences that I have in my API request where I sum up the values from a map. Then I want to display the variable in my widget inside a dialog. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
 Future<List<Presence>> getPresencesByAthleteId() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          Map map = json.decode(response.body);
          List<Presence>? presencesList = [];
          map.forEach((key, value) {
            presencesList.add(Presence(
                date: map.entries.first.key, count: map.entries.first.value));
            var values = map.values;
            var totalPresences = values.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element); //this I want to display it in a text
          });
          return presencesList.toList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e.toString());
    }
    return getPresencesByAthleteId(depId, teamId, id, context);
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                ...
                  secondary: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.history_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.black, size: 25),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (_athlete[i].currentMonthPresences! > 0) {
                                    showDialog(
                                       context: context,
                                     builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return SimpleDialog(
                                   children: [
                                   Column(
                                  FutureBuilder<List<Presence>>(
                         future: getPresencesByAthleteId(_athlete[i].department!.id, widget._team.teamKey!.teamId, _athlete[i].id, context),                                                                 
                       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {                                                                                
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {                                                                         
                 ...
            }),
            );
           } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
         }
      }),
     Container(
     child:
        Row(
          children: [
            const Text(''), // HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY totalPresences
            )
           ],
          ),
         ),
```

Comment: You mean in your FutureBuilder with "snapshot.data"?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track: 1) define a dialog (or equivalent) to display "totalPresences", 2) define a callback to invoke your API, and read the return value(s), then finally 3) Invoke your display.  Q: The code you're showing is in a [Stateful widget](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-stateful-vs-stateless-widgets/), correct?  And it has a [createState()](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive) method, right?  Here's a good example using a "Future" in a "Stateful widget": https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-futurebuilder-widget-examples

Comment: @VincentDR no it's outside my FutureBuilder

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes it's a Stateful Widget but I had to minimize the code. I should define the callback in my initState?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought I just needed a setState inside my api request like this:

int total=0;

```
Future<List<Presence>> getPresencesByAthleteId() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          Map map = json.decode(response.body);
          List<Presence>? presencesList = [];
          map.forEach((key, value) {
            presencesList.add(Presence(
                date: map.entries.first.key, count: map.entries.first.value));
            var values = map.values;
            var totalPresences = values.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element); 
              setState(() {
              totalPresences = total;
            });
          });
          return presencesList.toList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e.toString());
    }
    return getPresencesByAthleteId(depId, teamId, id, context);
  }
```

and then just display in dialog

```
.
.
  const Text($total),
```